# Replacing key-values in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary like this :

```
{
"name": "Hayagreeva", //String
"age": 3,  //Number
"subjects": {  //Array
    "rhymes": {   //Dictionary 1
        "test1": 10,
        "test2": 20,
        "test3": 30
    },
    "games": {  //Dictionary 2
        "test1": 40,
        "test2": 50,
        "test3": 60
    },
    "crayoning": { //Dictionary 3
        "test1": 70,
        "test2": 80,
        "test3": 90
    }
},
"date": "2008-02-16T10:06:00Z"  //Date
}
```

Now I need to replace the value for key subjects > games > test1 from 40 to value 60. I know the lenghty process of taking another dictionary objects and create a similar dictionary but that process is time consuming and may be a wrong strategy. I have searched many questions also here but all of them have the way to remove the key for the first level dictionary (like removing key "subjects" in the above code). So I want to know if there is an easy and efficient way to update the value for key in an inner level as I need to execute this process at many situations in my current project. Thanks in advance.

Edit : I also tried something like

```
[dict removeValueForKey:@"subjects.games.test1"];
```

But that doesn't work. I hope that this line helps you to understand the desired functionality by me.

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/AndrewShmig/ASADeepDictionary

Comment: This helps in creating a new dictionary but what I need is 

I want to replace the value of a key present deep in a dictionary and preserve my own dictionary simultaneously.

Comment: it allows not only creation but editing too.

Comment: I tried initializing it with my dictionary and passed the keypath with the value to replace with but instead it created a new dictionary with the only replaced key .

Comment: please, show me your code

Answer (score 3):

**If** that structure is *set in stone* and will not change then it's as simple as:

```
NSDictionary *topLevelDict = ...;
topLevelDict[@"subjects"][@"games"] = @{
    @"test1" : @(60),
    @"test2" : @(50),
    @"test3" : @(60)
};
```

Dictionaries of dictionaries are a pain to manipulate and it's always better to create a custom model object that allows easier manipulation, validation with the additional benefit of domain-specific functionality like serialization etc.

Comment: Can you please tell me what to do if "games" is an array of 3 dictionaries ? 
I will accept your answer if it works.

Comment: @PradeepMittal In that case there will be an additional level of dictionary sub-scripts to use when assigning (i.e. `topLevelDict[@"subjects"][@"games"][@"another_dict"]`).

Comment: how to give index then ? If games is an array and there is another_dict key at all 3 indexes ?